# Make requests to Google API with Python

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-source-repos

I'm trying to make requests to the Google API to create source repositories using a service account and his JSON key file.
Since there are no client libraries for this product, I am using the queries with Python using this documentation
https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/reference/rest

I already used a similar code to invoke my cloud-functions with success, but this time I'm block for these requests at the 401 error. I set up the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS with the JSON of my service account, give the service-account the permissions of Source Repository Administrator, but still return 401.

Here's my code

```py
import urllib.request
import json
import urllib
import google.auth.transport.requests
import google.oauth2.id_token

body = { "name" : "projects/$my_project_name/repos/$name_repo"}
jsondata = json.dumps(body).encode("utf8")
req = urllib.request.Request('https://sourcerepo.googleapis.com/v1/projects/$my_project_name/repos')
req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')

auth_req = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
id_token = google.oauth2.id_token.fetch_id_token(auth_req, 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform')
req.add_header("Authorization", f"Bearer {id_token}")
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req, jsondata)
print (response.read().decode())
```

I tried also using the with an API-KEY at the end of the url like this

```py
req = urllib.request.Request('https://sourcerepo.googleapis.com/v1/projects/$my_project_name/repos?key=$my-api-key')
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried also using the with an API-KEY at the end of the url like this

API Keys are not supported.

Your code is using an OIDC Identity Token instead of an OAuth Acess Token.

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    '/path/to/key.json',
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])


request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
credentials.refresh(request)
```

// Use the following code to add the access token:

```
req.add_header("Authorization", f"Bearer {credentials.token}")
```

Comment: for me it is not working ERROR is - "AttributeError: module 'google.auth.transport.requests' has no attribute 'get' ", could @John help on this. Using everything you said...

Comment: @IndrajeetGour - create a new question with your code, imports, error, etc.

Comment: @JohnHanley, I posted my question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71562904/google-service-account-authentication-for-api-call-using-python