# Google Service account authentication for API call using python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

Wanted to call out one GCP api from my python code, following is that method -

```
import google
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import google.auth.transport.requests
import requests

def get_window(self):
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        self.default_credentials, scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']
    )
    request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
    credentials.refresh(request)

    # Make an authenticated API request
    request_url = "https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-projectid/instances/my-instanceid"
    headers = {"Authorization", f"Bearer {credentials.token}"}
    req = requests.get(request_url, headers=headers)
    print(req.text)
```

When I call this method, following is the response:

```
request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
AttributeError: module 'google.auth.transport' has no attribute 'requests'
```

I am using python 3.9 on my local install packages are:

#### pip freeze

```
aiohttp==3.8.1
aiosignal==1.2.0                 
async-timeout==4.0.2             
attrs==21.4.0                    
cachetools==5.0.0                
certifi==2021.10.8               
googleapis-common-protos==1.56.0
httplib2==0.20.4
idna==3.3
multidict==6.0.2
protobuf==3.19.4
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pycparser==2.21
pyOpenSSL==22.0.0
pyparsing==3.0.7
requests==2.27.1
rsa==4.8
six==1.16.0
uritemplate==4.1.1
urllib3==1.26.9
yarl==1.7.2
```

Comment: Remove **import google**. That is a deprecated package that is breaking your other code.

Comment: Your import list shows that you have not installed the required Google Python packages. Follow the documentation to set up the Python SDK. https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/setup

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley I am able to run my code now

Comment: What was the solution?

Comment: I installed the google auth library and used import for right module which I missed from the last thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`google.auth.transport` is a package, not a module, so the correct way to import it would be

```
import google.auth.transport.requests
```

or if you prefer

```
from google.auth.transport import requests
```